# Ember event dispatching not working on input element

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have this input element:

```
{{input type="search" id="search" key-press="search" key-down="doSomething" autocomplete="off"}}
```

The key-press action is rightly called every time I hit a key, but for a reason I don't understand, the key-down action is called on every key-press. I.e. both actions are called.
I searched quite a bit, but nothing helped so far... .

Comment: So what do you think should happen? Have you [researched](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=keydown%20vs%20keypress) what the difference is between `key-down` and `key-press`?

Comment: that's the expected behavior..what do you expect ? and what is your use case ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what should happen. When you press the key without releasing - a `keyDown` event is triggered, if you release it - `keyPress` event is triggered.

You can remove one of the events in order to prevent future problems.